# How do I implement a parallel coordinates plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, matlab-figure, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to implement this plot

[image: plot]

Any ideas or advice for how to implement a parallel coordinates plot in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [parallelcoords](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/parallelcoords.html). Adding new Y-axis is done manually via line(...). Another way to make parallel coordinates plot is to use the function form [SAFE Toolbox](https://www.safetoolbox.info/)

Comment: is there any sample code i can take look? i dont totally understand by those document themself. thank you!

Comment: I googled ready-to-use [tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43611-parallel-coordinate-plots-gui-toolbox) in FEX. To add axes see Barnaby's answer 18Oct2013 and the tool's manual

Comment: +1 for alerting me to the fact that `parallelcoords` exists, because if I just search on the web I only find [parallelplot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallelplot.html) which is only in R2019a onwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB R2019a or later, you can use [parallelplot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parallelplot.html)

If you have an earlier version of MATLAB and you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, you can use [parallelcoords](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/parallelcoords.html)

There are some other implementations on the [MATLAB File Exchange](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=parallel+coordinate), of which [Interactive Parallel Coordinates](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/67410-interactive-parallel-coordinates) is worth a look.